# ASP.NET MVC Change Database value when checkbox is checked

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I have a really simple question. I have a form where if you check the checkbox and submit the form it changes the value to true (it's false by default). At the moment it doesn't work for me. So I am asking how should I do it?

Here's a few things how I do them. There's a value "IsConfirmed"

```
public virtual bool IsConfirmed {get;set;}
```

And I have a simple HttpPost method.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "UserName,Id,Email")] ApplicationUser formuser, string id, string RoleId)
    {
        var role = new ApplicationUser() { Id = formuser.Id, Email = formuser.Email, IsConfirmed = formuser.IsConfirmed };
        await UserManager.UpdateAsync(role);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Here's my view

```
@model CPO.Models.ApplicationUser
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary()
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
        </th>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Email)
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email)
               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserName)
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FirstName)
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LastName)
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownList("RoleId", "Select Role")
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsConfirmed)
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Edit" class="btn btn-default"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
}
@section Scripts {

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

}
```

Weirdly but it doesn't work and I have no idea why, maybe I missed to define something, but the model get's it's value as false even though it is checked.

---

*Any help is highly appreciated, If I made mistakes please be kind to write I made them in the comments and I'll fix them*

Comment: When you debug, where *exactly* is the value lost?  What is included in the POST request?  What is in the `model` object received by the controller action?  What is in the result of `model.ToDomainModel()`?  What is in the `commission` object?

Comment: Can you show your complete razor code also?

Comment: The value of `model.IsConfirmed` will be `true` if the checkbox is checked based on the code you have shown. Are you referring to the value of `commission.IsConfirmed`?

Comment: that's what I'm saying. it should be true but it gets false.

Comment: I added the ToDomainModel. And Sorry David, but that is too many questions to answer, basically you want all the code, but I can tell you the problem isn't where you're asking.

Comment: `Commission` does not contain any `bool` properties. You never even use the value of `IsConfirmed` so what is its purpose?

Comment: @StephenMuecke sorry, didn't insert that part, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: If its not working for you, then its due to code you have not shown us. And what is `Mapper.Map<`? (its even missing a closing `>`)

Comment: Mapper.Map is not the problem, do I have to show every implementation I have done? Mapper is for Mapping so that I could use ViewModel rather than model, because that is good practice. The problem is not that. The problem is that when the checkbox is checked it doesn't send the value as true. That's it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155338/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-highsepton).

Comment: This question might need some redefining, because clearly I didn't explain myself properly.

Comment: @HighSepton: `"basically you want all the code"` - No, but it is expected that you perform some debugging to narrow down the problem.  Nobody here can do that for you.  `"that is too many questions to answer"` - If debugging isn't worth your time then there's likely very little anybody here can do to help you.

Comment: @David well, I added what they asked for. See, I kind of changed my question and then understood that I changed the whole meaning of it. So I tried to explain people that that's not the problem. And it wasn't. But it was my big mistake, because I asked the question poorly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have excluded the `IsConfirmed` property from binding by your use of the `BindAttribute`

```
[Bind(Include = "UserName,Id,Email")]
```

which means only bind the values for properties `UserName`, `Id` and `Email`

Remove the attribute, or change it to include the property

```
[Bind(Include = "UserName, Id, Email, IsConfirmed")]
```

Note also you have excluded properties `FirstName`, `LastName` and `RoleId` from binding so there is little point including a form controls for them

Comment: Thanks for your help, you were very helpful !